# How to add git repo to working dir of a project

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a git repo in BitBucket, with a big project. I also have the same project locally on my computer in a dir, that is not under git. In my local dir, there are quite a few modifications that are not present in the repo, which I want to commit.

So, how do I sync the local dir, with the git repo, to be able to commit my changes and continue from there on. It's ok the changes to go in the master, I'm looking for the simplest possible solution.

Edit: For clarification, I've been working on SVN, had some uncommitted changes when I finally decided to switch to GIT. So I imported the SVN history to GIT using `git-svn`, then disconnected the local project from SVN.

Comment: Maybe by create a symlink between those two categories?

Comment: Clone the repo then copy your local project into the clone. Mind you this isn't syncing by any definition of the term: you'll be overwriting everything with your local version.

Comment: (If you have a Git repo for your project, why are you working from a non-git copy?)

Answer (score 5):

Set up a Git repo in the working directory:

```
git init
```

Commit whatever you have:

```
git add .
git commit
```

(The `git add .` assumes you have no files to ignore; maybe do this per file or copy over the `.gitignore`.)

Now, add the Bitbucket repo as a remote:

```
 git remote add origin <url>
```

Pull and rebase from Bitbucket:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

And when you're satisfied with the results, push them:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: You might also want to set the BitBucket `master` as the upstream for the local branch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will now try it and accept if everything works. @millimoose How would I do that?

Comment: @Veseliq You can do that when pushing changes back to bitbucket with `git push --set-upstream origin master`. That will let you avoid having to specify the branch the next time you pull/push.